C# and .NET 4.6.1 Spawn child process under a different parent process
I'm trying to write an app that will spawn a child process under a different parent than itself, and also I need to get its output.
Mostly it will be under explorer.exe of the same user context, which shouldn't cause any Windows security issues. I'm trying to make this work for Windows 7 and up, and I am also trying to get this to work as a normal user, not administrator.
The issue I'm having is that it doesn't seem like it's spawning the child under the new parent. If I spawn it under the process of the app, it works fine, not sure what I am doing wrong.
I have looked at text and it doesn't seem to be helping.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using NLog;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.IO;
using NPOI.SS.Formula.Functions;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public int nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct STARTUPINFOEX
{
    public STARTUPINFO StartupInfo;
    public IntPtr lpAttributeList;
}

public enum HANDLE_FLAGS : uint
{
    None = 0,
    INHERIT = 1,
    PROTECT_FROM_CLOSE = 2
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public int cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public int dwX;
    public int dwY;
    public int dwXSize;
    public int dwYSize;
    public int dwXCountChars;
    public int dwYCountChars;
    public int dwFillAttribute;
    public int dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public int dwProcessId;
    public int dwThreadId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SIZE_T
{
    public UIntPtr _value;
}

namespace LaunchProcess
{
    public static class LaunchProcess
    {
        private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x02000000;
        const int ProcessParentPid = 0x00000002;
        public const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;
        public const int STARTF_USESTDHANDLES = 0x00000100;
        public const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
        public const ushort SW_HIDE = 0x0000;
        public const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
        public const uint CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000;
        public const uint CreateSuspended = 0x00000004;

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(
        string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment, string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CreateProcess(
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            IntPtr lpProcessAttributes,
            IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFOEX lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
            IntPtr lpAttributeList, uint dwFlags, IntPtr Attribute, IntPtr lpValue,
            IntPtr cbSize, IntPtr lpPreviousValue, IntPtr lpReturnSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(
            IntPtr lpAttributeList, int dwAttributeCount, int dwFlags, ref IntPtr lpSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr lpAttributeList);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CreatePipe(out IntPtr hReadPipe, out IntPtr hWritePipe, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpPipeAttributes, uint nSize);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetHandleInformation(IntPtr hObject, uint dwMask, uint dwFlags);

        public static string CreateProcess(string processName, string command, string parentProcess = null)
        {
            Log.Trace($"Spawning {processName} with command {command}");

            const uint EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000;
            const int PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS = 0x00020000;

            // Create pipe for output capture
            IntPtr hReadPipe = IntPtr.Zero, hWritePipe = IntPtr.Zero;
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            securityAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(securityAttributes);
            securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = true;
            CreatePipe(out hReadPipe, out hWritePipe, ref securityAttributes, 0);
            SafeFileHandle safeReadPipe = new SafeFileHandle(hReadPipe, ownsHandle: false);
            SetHandleInformation(hReadPipe, 1, 0); // Prevent inheritance of the read pipe

            var pInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            var sInfoEx = new STARTUPINFOEX();
            sInfoEx.StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(sInfoEx);
            sInfoEx.StartupInfo.hStdOutput = hWritePipe;
            sInfoEx.StartupInfo.dwFlags |= 0x00000100; // Set the STARTF_USESTDHANDLES flag
            IntPtr lpValue = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool processCreated = false; // Flag to indicate if the process was created successfully
            string commandLine = $"{processName} {command}";
            var lpApplicationName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");

            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentProcess))
                {
                    Log.Trace($"Creating process with command: {commandLine}");

                    // Create the process
                    //processCreated = CreateProcess(null, commandLine, ref pSec, ref tSec, false, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo);
                    processCreated = CreateProcess(null, commandLine, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo);

                }
                else
                {
                    int PPID = GetParentProcessId(parentProcess);

                    if (PPID != -1)
                    {
                        var lpSize = IntPtr.Zero;
                        var success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 0, ref lpSize);

                        if (success || lpSize == IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            //Log.Error($"Failed to open parent process handle. Error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
                            return "";
                        }

                        sInfoEx.lpAttributeList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lpSize);
                        success = InitializeProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList, 1, 0, ref lpSize);
                        if (!success)
                        {
                            return "";
                        }

                        var parentHandle = Process.GetProcessById(PPID).Handle;
                        // This value should persist until the attribute list is destroyed using the DeleteProcThreadAttributeList function
                        lpValue = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
                        Marshal.WriteIntPtr(lpValue, parentHandle);

                        success = UpdateProcThreadAttribute(
                            sInfoEx.lpAttributeList,
                            0,
                            (IntPtr)PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS,
                            lpValue,
                            (IntPtr)IntPtr.Size,
                            IntPtr.Zero,
                            IntPtr.Zero);

                        if (!success)
                        {
                            return "";
                        }

                        var pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                        var tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                        pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
                        tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);
                        //var lpApplicationName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "notepad.exe");
                        processCreated = CreateProcess(lpApplicationName, null, ref pSec, ref tSec, false, EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref sInfoEx, out pInfo);
                    }
                }

                // Check if process was created successfully
                if (!processCreated)
                {
                    Log.Error($"CreateProcess failed. Error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}");
                    return "";
                }

                Log.Trace($"Created process with PID: {pInfo.dwProcessId}");

                Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pInfo.dwProcessId);
                proc.WaitForExit();

                // Read process output using a StreamReader
                string output = "";

                using (var outputStream = new FileStream(safeReadPipe, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(outputStream))
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
                    int read;

                    while ((read = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output += new string(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                }

                return output; // Return the captured output
            }
            finally 
            {
                // Free the attribute list
                if (sInfoEx.lpAttributeList != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    DeleteProcThreadAttributeList(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(sInfoEx.lpAttributeList);
                }
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(lpValue);

                // Close process and thread handles
                if (pInfo.hProcess != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(pInfo.hProcess);
                }

                if (pInfo.hThread != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    CloseHandle(pInfo.hThread);
                }

                if (hReadPipe != IntPtr.Zero) 
                { 
                    CloseHandle(hReadPipe);
                }

                if (hWritePipe != IntPtr.Zero)
                { 
                    CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
                }
            }
        }

        private static int GetParentProcessId(string processName)
        {
            // Find the process by the specified name
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

            if (processes.Length > 0)
            {
                Log.Trace($"Found {processName}.exe pid: {processes[0].Id}");
                return processes[0].Id;
            }
            else
            {
                int currentProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
                Log.Trace($"Failed to find {processName}.exe");
                Log.Trace($"Using current process pid: {currentProcessId}");
                return currentProcessId;
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is how I am calling it:
var results = LaunchProcess.CreateProcess("cmd.exe", "/c " + command, "explorer");

But when I watch the processes with Process Explorer, I don't see it creating a new process. Does anyone have any advice on how I can get this working?

Why are you running cmd to run explorer, why not run explorer directly? "when i watch the processes with Process Explorer I don't see it creating the new process." what do you see? Are there any logs from your error handling? I note most of your error handling does not check GetLastWin32Error it just return "". Also the handle in parentHandle needs to have PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS permissions, is that the case?

I'd also love to know why you are doing this, what usecase is there that depends on the exact parent process of something?

Im a instructor for cyber security, we run several scenarios were the students need to identify anomalous process running. Right now the program we use spawns it as a child of it. This means that when students find the parent that we are using for user emulation they will be able to quickly identify the process without trying.

The reason for the return of "" is this should be the return of the child process. Since it errors it should display nothing. Also I don't want to spawn a new parent I am trying to get it to spawn under explorer since when a user runs a program it will be a child of explorer depending on what it is. This test case is cmd.exe but will be expanded once I can get it working

Yeah I'm saying rather than just return "" you should throw a proper error using throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); that will give you a nice error message.
